# How do I write a cmdlet function to allow input "file" or pipeline?

Tags: powershell, parameters, pipeline

I'm trying to write a cmdlet that mirrors what UNIX commands like `cat` give me (reading from a file or standard input in the absence of a file). It needs to allows for the following possibilities:

```
cmdlet -file <inputFileName>
cmdlet -object <objectName>
<someObject> | cmdlet
```

I'm stretching the definition of "file" in this case to include arbitrary objects.

It has to process the parameters with the following priorities:

- If an object has been explicitly specified or made available in the pipeline, use that.
- Otherwise, use the file name.

My parameters are configured as:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "path")]
param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "path",
        Mandatory = $false,
        Position = 0)]
        [string] $file,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "object",
        Mandatory = $false,
        Position = 0,
        ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [Object] $object,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Int] $addrsize,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [String] $title
)
```

(I've put all the parameters in though I suspect the final two are not relevant).

So, there are two parameter sets, one with a string holding the file name, the other with an object, allowing for the object to be delivered in the pipeline.

In my `begin` block, I have the following code to read the file contents:

```
[byte[]] $bytes = $null
if($file) {
    $bytes = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes((Resolve-Path $file))
}
```

so, if you provide the `-file` argument, the array will be loaded with the file content.

In the `process` block, I examine the `-object` argument to see if it's there (as either an explicit argument or in the pipeline). If it is, I use that to overwrite the byte array with the object:

```
if (Test-Path variable:\object) {
    Write-Output "processing object" ## DEBUG code
    if ($object -is [Byte]) {
        $bytes = $object
    } else {
        $inputString = [string] $object
        $bytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($inputString)
    }
}
```

Now I fully understand that, if I use:

```
Write-Output "blah" | MyFunction -file myfile.txt
```

then the pipeline takes precedence and the file is ignored.

However, that seems to be happening even when I would expect that there's *no* pipeline:

```
MyFunction -file myfile.txt
```

The upshot is that, when I use that final statement above, the `bytes` array is set to empty and the file is therefore ignored.

How can I restructure this code to do what I desire? Is there another way to tell if the pipeline is empty so that I *don't* throw away the file content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Quick Answer

```powershell
if (Test-Path variable:\object)
```

This will be true even if the parameter is not passed, so it's always true as long as you have `$object` as a parameter possibility.

### To fix it:

You can do a few things. The easiest is just to use:

```powershell
if ($object)
```

Just like you did with `$file` in the `begin` block.

Since you're using parameter sets, you can also detect the parameter set name in use:

```powershell
if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'object')
```

## Other thoughts:

Since you're using parameter sets, you should make both `$file` and `$object` mandatory. After all, you want at least one of them to be supplied. They will only be mandatory in their respective parameter sets. The best way to see the results (especially with more complex parameter sets) is to execute the definition of your function so it's defined in the current scope, and then view the help:

```powershell
Get-Help MyFunction
```

That will show you exactly how powershell is interpreting your parameter sets (how many and which parameters are mandatory and optional in each).

`$file` *should* (but doesn't have to be) named `$Path` in keeping with Powershell's style. You can include an alias so that it will accept file as an alternate name by adding one or more `Alias` attributes:

```powershell
[Alias('File')]
```

Typically in a `process` block you want to use something like this:

```powershell
process {
    foreach($obj in $object) {
        # code that processes each object ($obj) in the pipeline
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that the behavior is different depending on whether you pass object in via a parameter or the pipeline. If you do `'file1','file2',file3' | MyFunction` then the process block will be called once for each file. But you if you call `MyFunction -object 'file1','file2','file3'` then the process block will be called **once** and `$object` will be an array. Using `foreach` lets you handle both cases the same way without any conditionals.

Your use of `Write-Object "processing object"` should probably be `Write-Verbose` or `Write-Debug`, which will only be shown when the function is called with `-Verbose` or `-Debug` respectively. You could also use `Write-Host` to always write to the screen, but [that is discouraged](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).

Comment: On that last point, it was just temp debug code but you've certainly given me a lot to look into, which I'll be doing as soon as I get back to the office. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Excellent answer, I implemented _all_ your suggestions and it works exactly as I wanted.